# Determine the most general Mobius transform that...

Tags: complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Determine the most general Mobius transform that satisfies:

i) two fixed points z=0 and z=1;

ii) maps the unit circle $|z|=1$ and the bisector of first and third quarter to lines.

My guess is: $$\frac{cz(1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i))}{cz \pm \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)}$$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$

May you tell me if it's correct?

edit: 
In the (ii) i want to say that the Mobius $$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ transformations takes the points of the complex plane $|z|=1$ and $z(t) = t e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$ in lines (so I infer that the point $-\frac{d}{c}$ is one of the two points of intersection between $|z|=1$ and $z(t) = t$.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by part (ii)

Comment: @DavidQuinn I've edited the question, I hope that now it'a clearer (sorry but I don't speak English as first language)

Comment: Do you mean that the circle $|z|=1$ is mapped to the line $y=x$?

Comment: no, I mean that the circle $|z|=1$ is mapped to a line and the line $y=x$ is mapped to a line. A mobius transform always maps lines and circles to circles except for lines and circles that go through $- \frac{d}{c}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to satisfy condition (i) we can write the transformation as $$w=\frac{az}{z+a-1}$$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$

We can rearrange and write this as $$z=\frac{w-aw}{w-a}$$

In order to apply the conditions in (ii), we can set $w=u+iv$ and $a=p+iq$

Firstly, the locus $|z|=1$ becomes $|w-aw|=|w-a|$ which is equivalent to $$(u(1-p)+qv)^2+(v(1-p)-qu)^2=(u-p)^2+(v-q)^2$$

For this to represent a line, we require the coefficients of $u^2$ and $v^2$ to be zero, each of which give the relation $$(1-p)^2+q^2=1$$

In addition the coefficient of $uv$ is identically zero.

Secondly, we require the image of the locus $Re(z)=Im(z)$ also to be a line, and after a few lines of algebra, we get $$q=p-1$$

So the possible values of $a$ are $$1\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$$